# Displaying custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display a custom post type in wordpress. I can display the themubnail but I would like to resize it according to the item type:

My code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$args = array('post_type' => 'package','package-category'=>'Kenya',  'posts_per_page'=>6 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

<?php 
    $item_type == '1/4 Grid Style';
    $item_class = $package_div_size_num_class[$item_type]['class'];
$item_size = $package_div_size_num_class[$item_type];

    function print_package_mythumbnail( $post_id, $item_size, $last_minute = 'normal-type',        $last_text = 'Read More' ){
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id , $item_size );
    $alt_text = get_post_meta($thumbnail_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    if( !empty($thumbnail) ){
        echo '<div class="package-media-wrapper gdl-image">';

        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $thumbnail[0] .'" alt="'. $alt_text .'"/>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';  // package-media-wrapper
    }   
}
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id , $item_size );
    $alt_text = get_post_meta($thumbnail_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    if( !empty($thumbnail) ){
        echo '<div class="package-media-wrapper gdl-image">';

        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $thumbnail[0] .'" alt="'. $alt_text .'"/>';

        if( !empty($last_minute) && !empty($last_text) ){
            echo '<div class="package-ribbon-wrapper">';
            echo '<div class="package-type ' . $last_minute . '">';
            echo $last_text;
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            echo '<div class="package-type-gimmick"></div>';
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</a>';

        echo '</div>';  // package-media-wrapper
    }
```

?>

Where `$item_type == '1/4 Grid Style'` is defined as:

```
$package_div_size_num_class = array(
    "1/4 Grid Style" => array(
        "no-sidebar"=>"400x300", 
        "one-sidebar"=>"400x400", 
        "both-sidebar"=>"400x400", 
        "class"=>"gdl-package-widget"
    )
)
```

How can I resize the thumbnail according to the item type?

Comment: you need to clarify this, what is the item type?

Comment: Thanks..item type is the size of the column

Answer (score 0):

quick fix using css (create a div for the image and set dimensions.)

in your style.css

```
.package-media-wrapper{
   min-width: 30%;
   max-width: 30% !important;
}

.package-image{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Your question is a bit confusing are you trying to detect how many sidebars are showing? In most templates this is set on the page template fairly late in the code?  To make changes to html you could detect what template is being used by

```
 if(is_page_template('2column')) {
     $imagehtml= ............;
 } else if (etc) {}
```

Other than that you are looking at query to get the attributes of a containing div (in your case the column size i guess?)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var width=jQuery('.package-media-wrapper').width();

  if(width===300px) {
    jQuery('.package-image').width('300px');
  }
 }
```